# Stop a service before unmounting file system during shutdown of a host

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-16.04

Can someone let me know how can I make a systemd service to be stopped first before the unmounting of the file system starts during the shutdown of a host?

Unit File looks like below

```
[Unit]
Description=FDB Service
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Environment=FDB_PID_DIR=/var/run/fdb/
Environment=LOCKFILE=/var/run/fdb/fdbmonitor.pid

Type=simple
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
IgnoreSIGPIPE=false

ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/ubuntu/build-target/fdb/fdb-sysd-start.sh
ExecStopPost=-/home/ubuntu/build-target/fdb/fdb-sysd-poststop.sh

RestartSec=2s
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- OS - `Ubuntu 16.04.6`

Comment: This should happen automatically unless you've created some oddball filesystems, remote mounts, or something else strange. What are your filesystems? And what is the unit file of the affected service?

Comment: Ok but as per http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/systemd-halt.service.8.html second para in the description, it states that unmount filesystem and then kill all services.

Comment: huh? That man page doesn't say anything like that. It's also not relevant because you don't call that service directly. It is called by systemd itself after all services are stopped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is almost certainly a problem with your service (fdb). systemd will first try to stop all services and then do the unmount. Make sure your service stops in a reasonable time - if it needs more time to stop gracefully, you may set `TimeoutStopSec=` to a higher value. Also, make sure `Type=simple` is appropriate, from what it looks `Type=forking` might be better. When switching to `Type=forking` make use of PID file by adding `PIDFile=/var/run/fdb/fdbmonitor.pid` - if it actually contains the main process PID.

If you are using network-mounted shares, systemd should detect them and unmount before shutting down the network. If that does not happen, add `_netdev` mount option to tell systemd this is actually a network share.

Comment: Can you explain why Type=forking will be better?

Comment: See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=
`[...] The parent process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all communication channels are set up. The child continues to run as the main service process, and the service manager will consider the unit started when the parent process exits. This is the behavior of traditional UNIX services. [...]`

This looks as if this .sh script starts some other process, that's why I took a guess